# Is there any way to send and receive SMS through my Prolink PHS300 3g modem?

Tags: modem, 3g, modem-manager

Is there any way to send and receive SMS through my 3g modem. I'm using prolink phs300 modem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Gnome Phone Manager - package `gnome-phone-manager`

http://live.gnome.org/PhoneManager